# How to hide part of unused variable at script startup

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How I can hide variable from using when it is not defined with bash command with this situation:

```
EXCLUDE_PORTS="--exclude-ports $2"

if [ "${EXCLUDE_PORTS:-}" == "" ]; then
    EXCLUDE_PORTS=''
fi
```

I need to hide also --exclude-ports, when $2 it is not specified. Actually when I don't specified $2 at script startup, script take only first part empty "--exclude-ports", and this is ruining my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a shorthand for this:

```
EXCLUDE_PORTS=${2:+--exclude-ports $2}
```

The shorthand is `${var:+ <alternate value>}` which is empty if `var` is unset or empty, and else is substituted by the alternate value.

Now, if you combine this with [Léa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63220480/7233423):

```
EXCLUDE_PORTS=( ${2:+--exclude-ports "$2"} )
```

Answer (score 5):

Always use/prefer an array when dynamically building arguments:

```sh
if [ -n "$2" ]
then EXCLUDE_PORTS=( '--exclude-ports' "$2" )
else EXCLUDE_PORTS=()
fi

echo command "${EXCLUDE_PORTS[@]}" --other-option
```

Comment: Look's good, but I must have --exclude-ports and $2 in one line, not separated. I need like this: "--exclude-ports 22 80 111", but then EXCLUDE_PORTS=( '--exclude-ports $2' ) this syntax not working.

Comment: @hock Then add the additional 22 80 and 111 to the EXCLUDE_PORTS array Like: ` shift; if [ $[ $# -gt 0 ]; then EXCLUDE_PORTS=( '--exclude-ports' "$@" ); else EXCLUDE_PORTS=(); fi`.

Answer (score 3):

### Use Built-In Conditional Expressions; Verify with Parameter Expansion

You can refactor this to a single line using the built-in [conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) and the Boolean `&&` [conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs). It's also a good idea to use proper quoting. For example:

```
[[ -n "$2" ]] && EXCLUDE_PORTS="--exclude-ports '$2'"
```

You can verify the logic here with the `:-` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) like so:

```
# make sure your environment is clean for testing
unset EXCLUDE_PORTS

# set exactly two positional arguments
set -- one two

# set variable if $2 zero length when expanded
[[ -n "$2" ]] && EXCLUDE_PORTS="--exclude-ports '$2'"

# print variable if set, or message to aid debugging
echo "${EXCLUDE_PORTS:-variable is empty}"
```

> ```
> # --exclude-ports 'two'
> ```

When you only have one positional parameter:

```
unset EXCLUDE_PORTS
set -- one
[[ -n "$2" ]] && EXCLUDE_PORTS="--exclude-ports '$2'"
echo "${EXCLUDE_PORTS:-variable is empty}"
```

> ```
> variable is empty
> ```

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm do it wrong but I have: 

./test.sh 1
./test.sh: 5: ./test.sh: [[: not found
variable is empty

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
EXCLUDE_PORTS="--exclude-ports $2"
if [[ $2 == "" ]] || [[ "${EXCLUDE_PORTS:-}" == "" ]]; then
    EXCLUDE_PORTS=''
fi
```

All you need is an OR `||`

Comment: The `|| [[ "${EXCLUDE_PORTS:-}" == "" ]]` check can simply be deleted. The string will never be empty seeing as it is set to a non-empty string the line before.